# how do I prevent harmful data from being injected into img src if I echo data from php?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

A little background of this problem wouldn't hurt I think:
I have a webservice to which I can upload images and then retrieve them by id via an api call. The return value is a link to an actual image on the server. However, that data is easy to substitute if the request is hijacked.

So the problem that arises from this is that you can replace the link with `" onerror="alert(whatever);` and it would alert the user with 'whatever' because this link is placed into `<img src="<?= api/get.php?image_id=x ?>" />` becoming `<img src="" onerror"alert(whatever);" />`.

How do I go about preventing that from happening? Is there a way to maybe escape the link before inserting it into the image tag? Or better yet base64 the link?

I have tried and failed using:
 1. urlencode()
 2. base64_encode()

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

P.S. I cannot send base64 encoded images since I need to able to copy image's link easily.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your logic right. But you send an id through a get request and send an image url back. A user will alway be able to adjust the src of an image. 
You have to make sure the image_id you send gets validated correctly then get the url from a database and send the url back

Comment: that's exactly what's being done on the server, if you send an invalid image id the server will just reject your request and send a 'no-image'-link back. the question is about some third guy hijacking and faking server's answer

Comment: As long the id gets validated right and the repsponse of your server is right, there is nothing you can do about if some one change the src of the image tag

Comment: true but I can at least prevent that injection from being executed, it's better to have broken image all over the page than have potentially malicious code being executed

Comment: You Can't, Your server will send an url back if the user adjust the url you can nothing do about that. Of what malicious code you are afraid of?

Comment: what do you mean I can't? if the response from the server will be htmlspecialchars()'d on client's side then it'll become useless in sense of doing something bad, the browser will parse it as a relative link.

Im afraid of any malicious code, whether it is just a funny alert message or whatever

Comment: As you say in the post below, your server create the file name. You create the url on your server and thats what the user will get as response.

Comment: they will unless someone hijacks server's response and substites the data in that response

Comment: And then what? As long the code on your server is generating  the response. Any one can change the data they get returned, add javascript into a src or something but that will only take place on his browser. Just make sure your file upload is save, the image_id in your get request gets validated right and the code on your server will generate the image url

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this question SO suggested some related topics where I found out that `htmlspecialchars()` works wonderfully solving this problem. However, this still might not be enough because this only works for my use-case, not every possible one. Please feel free to suggest more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the first problem is you are allowing a user to control the filename. If you are controlling and hosting the uploads, generate a guid and use that to store the file. Removing the ability for users to control the filename removes the chance they can add a `"` to break out of your `<img src"` context.

I don't see why `urlencode()` would fail. As long as a `"` is displaying as `%22` that will prevent that data from breaking out of the attribute context.

You also do need to ensure that `<>` characters are encoded as well. For this you may want to use `htmlentities()`

Comment: custom filenames arent allowed, if you upload an image to my webservice it will automatically get a uniqid() name. so there is no way a filename would have some malicious code contained in it when server answers your response.
the situation Im trying to prevent is when someone hijacks server's response and substitutes it with not even a link to some other image but a piece of malicious code

Comment: img's src attribute doesn't understand urlencode()'d links like 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8001%2Fupload%2F2020%2F06%2F09%2F5edf4cb8d570f6.12579519.jpg', it just shows a broken image